# Multi-threaded Behaviour of computeIfAbsent with a Long Running Operation

Tags: java, multithreading

The following code is taken from Java: Concurrency in Practice. The author iteratively builds a scalable, thread-safe cache, and the following is the final version.

```
public class Memoizer<A, V> implements Computable<A, V> {
    private final ConcurrentMap<A, Future<V>> cache
        = new ConcurrentHashMap<A, Future<V>>();
    private final Computable<A, V> c;

    public Memoizer(Computable<A, V> c) { this.c = c; }

    public V compute(final A arg) throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            Future<V> f = cache.get(arg);
            if (f == null) {
                Callable<V> eval = new Callable<V>() {
                    public V call() throws InterruptedException {
                        return c.compute(arg);
                    }
                };
                FutureTask<V> ft = new FutureTask<V>(eval);
                f = cache.putIfAbsent(arg, ft);
                if (f == null) { f = ft; ft.run(); }
            }
            try {
                return f.get();
            } catch (CancellationException e) {
                cache.remove(arg, f);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                throw launderThrowable(e.getCause());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically if a thread has already started a long-running expensive computation, the other thread doing a `get()` on the same key will wait and not recompute. I was wondering why the author didn't simply use `computeIfAbsent()` here?

```
public class Memoizer<A, V> implements Computable<A, V> {
    private final ConcurrentMap<A, Future<V>> cache
        = new ConcurrentHashMap<A, Future<V>>();
    private final Computable<A, V> c;

    public Memoizer(Computable<A, V> c) { this.c = c; }

    public V compute(final A arg) {
        cache.computeIfAbsent(arg, k -> c.compute(arg));
        return cache.get(arg);
    }
}
```

This code exhibits the same behaviour: Since the operation is atomic, only one thread initiates the computation and other threads wait. If the operation fails, the compute method can return a `null` and will be reinvoked by other threads. Is there any specific reason why it was not used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multithreaded behaviour is **not** the same with regards to other threads that want to memoize the result for other arguments.

The documentation for [`ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) explicitly states:

> Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and simple.

With the authors solution threads that need the memoized for other arguments are only blocked for a short duration (during `putIfAbsent()`), but with `computeIfAbsent()` some of them may be blocked for the whole duration of the expensive calculation.

Comment: Makes sense, should have read the docs better. However, I tried updating the map with two different keys - One that triggers a long computation, one that triggers a short one. The long one is different before the short one, yet the short one completes earlier and returns the corresponding value. Doesn't seem like for different keys, it blocked (in this case). For same keys, yes, all threads all blocked while the computation is gong on.

Comment: typo: ...The long one is triggered before the short one...